# Rails - the best way to display a set of results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Hotel model, with the model having a location field.

I want to be able to filter hotels so that it only displays the results that the user searches for, by location.

e.g. a user searches for 'Madrid', the page will then redirect to a list of hotels found in Madrid.

What would the easiest way be to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please, read some basic tutorials, SO is not a 'write-my-code-instead-of-me' service.

Comment: I've read plenty, thanks. The app already has plenty of functionality -- I was just struggling with this one particular problem, no matter how basic it might appear. If I had a location model, then I would have found this considerably easier. Still, I'm so sorry to have troubled you.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to query the DB filtering by city:

```
city_hotels = Hotel.where(city: params[:city])
```

Comment: This works, and this was my initial idea; however, it then gets confused with the show method. Should I define an additional route to get around this?

Comment: You can define additional method plus additional route, and use the same view you use for show. Or for :index, should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest simply using a `where` clause.  Something like:

```
Hotel.where(location: 'Madrid')
```

Since this maps to a SQL `SELECT` statement, it has your database do the work before retrieving the data and it will give you an array of objects to work with.  If you have multiple conditions then you can string them together by using a string setup instead like:

```
Hotel.where('location LIKE ? AND name LIKE ?', '%Madrid%', '%Hilton%')
```

This will give you flexibility to create your own queries without putting too much stress on your API server.  If you, for example, use `all` or `findAllBy` then Rails will load all the hotels onto the API layer then go through each one individually (takes processing time and CPU).  However, using `where` in these situations makes it so that the database (which is designed to do these kinds of queries) handles the work which minimizes API CPU usage so more people's API requests can go through.

As a side note, if you're working with a rarely changing query (like all hotels near a city) it may be worth while to look into caching the answers to save on processing time.  Hotels, for example, don't just pop up overnight so caching a list of hotels in Madrid for a period of time (like 4-8 hours) means that you're only processing the request once.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the in depth answer! I really appreciate it. I did manage to get it working to some extent by using the `.where` clause inside of the index action. What would be the best way of defining a new action to display these hotels as to avoid modifying the index? Thanks again!

Comment: I would suggest setting up a controller that houses the logic for you.  You can then map the endpoints to the controller method.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#saving-data-in-the-controller gives a good example of how to set up controllers that show the data.